# How to show data from GraphQL server to npm react-table?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-table

I've been starting working with `GraphQL server` and `Apollo client`. The code is written in `Reactjs`. Now I want to get data from GraphQL server using any queries, and show data to the table in the UI. I use npm `react-table` for table.

[The table could look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qpp3.png)

I can easily get and show data if the query response has no array. For example, I have the query input string below:

```
{
  account {
    firstName
    lastName
    id
  }
}
```

And query result with no array

```
{
  "data": {
    "account": {
      "firstName": "Marlen",
      "lastName": "Marquardt",
      "id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

In ReactTable component, I just fetch the data using `data.account.firstName`

```
<ReactTable
  data={[
    {
      firstName: data.account.firstName,
      lastName: data.account.lastName,
      id: data.account.id,
    }
  ]}
  columns={columns}
/>
```

However, if query result has array I don't know how to fetch the data. Please take a look the picture
[query result with array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRbfG.png)

So how can I show all 5 toy's `title` to table ? 
This is my old code:

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './Test.css';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css';

const localURL = 'http://localhost:3000/graphql';
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: localURL, fetch }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
const columns = [
  {
    Header: "ID",
    accessor: "id"
  },
  {
    Header: "First Name",
    accessor: "firstName"
  },
  {
    Header: "Last Name",
    accessor: "lastName"
  }
]

class Table extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> ADMIN </h2>
        <ReactTable
          data={[
            {
              firstName: data.account.firstName,
              lastName: data.account.lastName,
              id: data.account.id,
            }
          ]}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const queryAccountList = gql`
  query {
    account{
      firstName
      lastName
      id
      }
    }
  }
`

const AccountListWithData = graphql(queryAccountList)(Table);

export default AccountListWithData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, your ReactTable's data prop expects an array (or at least, in your example you're passing it an array of 1 object).

Note also that the data object returned by your GraphQL is of the form

```
  {
    account
    {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      id
    }
  }
```

So you could have defined your ReactTable data with `data={[ data.account ]}` with the same result.

Now let's say you perform your Toys query, then the data returned will be of the form

```
{
  allToy [
    {
      id,
      title
    },
    {
      id,
      title
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

so if your definition of data remains the same (`const { data } = this.props;`), then `data.allToy` will be an array of `{ id, title }` objects.

So you can define your Toy ReactTable as:

```
<ReactTable
  data={ data.allToy }
  columns={columns}
  defaultPageSize={10}
/>
```

Comment: In case my query response contains sub-array. How can I get the data ? Please take a look the picture: https://imgur.com/a/abOj4

Comment: The real problem here is, does ReactTable accept an array as value for a data cell. If it does, then you do not need to do anything specific, you can just pass `data.allToys` to your ReactTable. If it does not, you have to find another way to display your data. What I am trying to say here is that accessing the data is not the problem, it is more of a presentational issue you are dealing with: how to display nested arrays in a two-dimensional table.